# Bayes Estimator under Squared Error Loss of Conditional Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, bayesian, parameter-estimation

Let $X$ be a single observation such that given $\Lambda=\lambda$, $X|\Lambda=\lambda$ follows the Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$.  Put a prior distribution on $\Lambda$, say $\pi(\lambda)$, with pdf:

$$\pi(\lambda)=\frac{\lambda^{\tau-1}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{\mu}}}{\Gamma(\tau)\mu^\tau}$$

Find the Bayes estimator of $\lambda$ under squared error loss.

I find that the distribution of $\Lambda|X$ ends up being $GAMMA(\tau+\sum x_i, (\frac{1}{\mu}+n)^{-1})$, which implies that the Bayes estimator under squared error loss is simply the product of the parameters:

$$\lambda_{Bayes}=\frac{\tau+\sum x_i}{\frac{1}{\mu}+n}$$

Where $n$, in this context, is the number of collected samples.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the Bayes estimator under squared error loss is the mean, which is the product of the two parameters.